# Where is it shown that a countable self-injective ring is semilocal?

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras

In `Lawrence, John. "A countable self-injective ring is quasi-Frobenius." Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society (1977): 217-220.` the first line is this:

> It has been known for some time that a countable self-injective ring is
>   semilocal (see for example [8].)

Where [8] is `Renault, Guy. "Sur les anneaux de groupes." CR Acad. Sci. Paris Sér. AB 273 (1971): A84-A87.`

The problem is that Renault's paper, as far as I know, says nothing of the sort. There is a result about semilocal group rings (which does not mention self-injectivity or countability) and a result on self-injective group rings (which proves the group ring must be semilocal) but nothing in general about "countable self-injective rings."

I'm also pretty familiar with everything else cited in Lawrence's paper, and I don't think it was a case of the wrong bibliography item being cited. I can see is that a method like the one used by Gentile will prove that a countable, right self-injective ring is semi local, although I can’t see that it is explicit in Gentile’s paper.

Is anyone aware of a reference that proves such a thing in the box above? It could perhaps be a different Renault paper.

Or maybe you can explain how that statement actually follows from Renault's paper. I [prepared a translation of it](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.08586.pdf) so I thought I should immediately see where that might be explained, but who knows: maybe I'm overlooking something obvious.

Comment: You could, of course, contact John Lawrence. He is retired, but still active mathematically.

Comment: @DavidHandelman Ok, I'll try that too. Quite often when I ask someone "what did you mean when you wrote this 40 years ago" the answer is indeterminate, but it's worth a shot :)